# Call popViewController from Class Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'd like to go back to my root view from within a class method of view 1. When in an instance method of view 1, i would just say

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but since `self` doesn't apply in a class method, I am wondering how to accomplish this. Pertaining to the illustration below, I am currently in a class method of View1Controller.m and I'd like to get back to Rootview. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you refactor your class to make it an instance method instead of a class method?  Is there any reason your method needs to be a class method?

Comment: I made it a class method because I need to access it from a SKPaymentTransactionObserver class. This is my first go-round with In-App Purchase and I am struggling with this concept of having a separate class for the observer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare another method:

```
-(void)closeThisViewController
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
}
```

Then use NotificationCenter:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notif_closeThisVC" selector:@selector(closeThisViewController) object:nil];
```

Although as jonkroll said, you're dealing with view controller stuff, we don't understand why you would put view controller related code inside a class method.

### Edit

Sorry bad code above.

I meant to say you can use NSNotificationCenter to post a notification:

```
-(void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
```

Then in the same view controller declare a NSNotificationCenter observer:

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver selector:(SEL)notificationSelector name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
```

My brain was quicker than my fingers, so I kinda combined the two into one when I tried to explain the solution :P

It should more like this:

```
// posting a notification with NSNotificationCenter
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notif_closeThisVC" object:nil];
```

In your viewDidLoad method somewhere (I recommend at the top), add this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    // adding an observer with NSNotificationCenter
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closeThisViewController) name:@"notif_closeThisVC" object:nil];

    ...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm looking at the docs for NSNotificationCenter, but I do not see the method you have shown. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Oh sorry, bad code. You use the "postNotificationName:object:" method, you'll also need your NSNotificationCenter addObserver method in the same view controller "addObserver:selector:name:object:"

Comment: Wow. Did not know of the NSNotificationCenter class. Thank you very much for bringing that to my attention and providing a detailed response. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to refactor this from a class method to an instance method (and there are certainly cases where you wouldn't want to do that), I'd suggest you add a completion block parameter to your class method:

```
+ (void)doSomethingWithCompletion:(void(^)())completion {
    /* Do your thing... */
    completion();
}

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender {
     [self.class doSomethingWithCompletion:^{
          [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     }];
}
```

This would allow you to cleanly separate the instance-less operation the class method performs from instance-specific dismissing of the view controller. You could also make the completion block accept an error object if the operation can fail.

You could do something similar with a delegate object or even by passing in the view controller to dismiss, but this design seems to offer the cleanest separation with the most modern feel.

Comment: Seems fine and dandy until he needs to access the instance's `navigationController` in order to pop.

Comment: The "self" inside the block refers to the instance (`-doSomething:`'s `self`), not the class (`+doSomethingWithCompletion:`'s `self`). The block is said to "close over" the variables around it, which is why many languages call blocks "closures".

Comment: Following that logic, you may want to use a weakself pointer, otherwise your retained closure is going to cause all kinds of problems with memory.

Comment: `self` would not be able to be deallocated if it were still on the `navigationController`'s stack, in which case the completion is going to do the wrong thing (pop some other view controller off the stack) anyway. If you want to code defensively, though, you could add an `NSAssert(self.navigationController.topNavigationController == self, @"I'm still at the top of the navigation stack")` in the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be legitimate arguments that encourage you to refactor so that you do have access to the current view controller and can access the navigation controller via `currentVC.navigationController`. Remember, it can still be a class method, just give it an extra argument when you call it (or start the call chain that calls it) from the VC.

However, I also had to solve this in one of my apps, so I just made sure that the navigation controller was globally accessible to everyone, always via pointer ("weak ref")

If you declare a global variable like this (say, in "Navigation.h")

```
extern UINavigationController *gNavController;
```

and define it in your `AppDelegate.m` (pays to review distinction between declaration/definition if you're rusty on that):

```
UINavigationController* gNavController;
```

and then assign it when you start up in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:
(assuming the delegate has a property called `viewController` that is your navigation controller):

```
gNavController = viewController;
```

Then as long as you `#import Navigation.h`, you'll always have access to the navigation controller. This also makes getting a handle to its view for popups/popovers much simpler.
This also assumes your nav controller is never released for the lifetime of the app (probably true unless you're doing something unusual).

Comment: As much as I hate to say this is correct, posting a notification is not only cleaner, but doesn't declare an extra global to a top level object.  This will create some memory management headaches.